# what's the possible problem when throwing large data to Trash

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a big Hive table that occupies aboult 2T space, I want to drop old partitions to save space.

When I drop partitons, the HDFS files will be moved to the Trash.

So I would ask what's the possible problem if I throw big data(maybe many files) to Trash, is there space issue? for example, exceeds the Trash's space capacity.

Comment: There won't be any space limit for Trash. But Namenode may experience GC Pause, RPC response time may increase

Comment: Thanks  @BruceWayne If I understood correctly,   I could do this during relatively idle time, such as 1am - 3am, then namenode issue may be relaxed?

Comment: I would recommend to try, when there is less load in the cluster. In your case 1am-3am. Or you can try truncating the table by picking selected partitions instead of bulk delete (drop)

Comment: Thanks @BruceWayne， I tried the `truncate  partition` option, it is perfect! The files under the partiton directory are removed, but these files are not sento to Trash, just like hdfs -skipTrush, this is exactly what I want for my case, thank you @BruceWayne